# EF Npgsql Core not generating temporary Id on Insert

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Recently I've migrated from EF Npgsql Core 2.2 to the 3.1.1.
All good, but now when using Add or AddRange methods from EF, a temporary Id isn't being sett on my entity.

Does anyone knows what can be the reason? Usually when I called add, a id value was sett with some random value like -1245343. I also tried to put the ValueGeneratedOnAdd for that table but no luck.

I'm going to put here the definition of a entity class, my DbContext, DI configuration for the DbContext, as well as the SQL script of the table.

**The Entity**

```
 public class StatementHeader : RFBaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public double TotalLocal { get; set; }
        public double TotalForeign { get; set; }

        .....
    }
```

**The DBContext**

```
public abstract class EFBaseContext : DbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EFBaseContext"/> class.
        /// Do not use for test only
        /// </summary>
        protected EFBaseContext()
        {
        }

        protected EFBaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Source>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Templates)
                .WithOne(x => x.Source);
            modelBuilder.Entity<StatementHeader>()
                .Property(i => i.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();
            modelBuilder.RemoveCascadeDeleteConvention();
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
}
```

**The Autofac DI container**

```
 var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EFCoreContext>()
                .UseNpgsql(WebApiConfigurations.ConnectionString, (x=>x.SetPostgresVersion(9,6)));

            builder.RegisterType<EFCoreContext>().As<DbContext>().WithParameter("options", dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options)
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE public."StatementHeader" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "CreatedOn" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "ModifiedOn" timestamp without time zone NULL,
    "CreatedByUserLogin" text NULL,
    "ModifiedByUserLogin" text NULL,
    "Description" text NULL,
    "TotalLocal" double precision NOT NULL,
    "TotalForeign" double precision NOT NULL,
    "Date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "Comments" text NULL,
    "TemplateId" integer NOT NULL,
    "PaymentReceivedId" integer NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_StatementHeader" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_StatementHeader_PaymentReceived_PaymentReceivedId" FOREIGN KEY ("PaymentReceivedId") REFERENCES public."PaymentReceived" ("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_StatementHeader_Template_TemplateId" FOREIGN KEY ("TemplateId") REFERENCES public."Template" ("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: Shortly, [EF Core 3.0 Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) - [Temporary key values are no longer set onto entity instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#tkv)

Comment: But is thre a way when adding a entity to retrieve it's temporary id and use it on other related entities? I was confused with this change, is there an example on how can we handle this situation now without having to rewrite part of the logic?

Comment: This really is a question for the people who did that breaking change. You can open a new issue or comment/ask/vote on the original [tracking issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12378).

Comment: If you're doing this for efficiency, i.e. to insert several related entities in a single roundtrip, you may want to look at http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html#hilo-autoincrement-generation. Otherwise take a look at the mitigations in the [breaking change note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#tkv).

Comment: Thanks. They break up ef core unfortunately its going to be very demanding and costly to upgrade all. Hope somethings are revised on next versions. I will stick with 2.2 for now, don't see any advantage on 3 for now